# In 14.04 how do I run a bash script I wrote without opening a terminal?

Tags: command-line, scripts, unity-dash

I use terminal a lot.  I wrote a script and have it in ~/blah/script.sh now.  How can I run the script from Unity (Dash?)?

A long time ago I would have used ALT-F2 and typed my command, but that doesn't do what I expect now.

Maybe modifying some $PATH var somewhere so dash can find it...?  I don't want to change the dir the script is in because it's in a place where I serve various scripts for reasons.

Tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply create a `.desktop` file and save it in `~/.local/share/applications`. In its most basic form:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=name_of_your_script_like_you_see_it_in_Dash
Exec=sh /path/to/script.sh
Icon=/path/to/some/icon
Type=Application
```

Copy it into an empty file, save it as `script.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications`.
After log out /in, it will appear in Dash.

If the script is executable, you can replace `Exec=sh /path/to/script.sh` by simply: `Exec=/path/to/script.sh`, or if you don't have the language extension on the script: `Exec=/path/to/script`

#### Note

If the path to your script contains (folder-) names with spaces, you can simply escape it by putting the name between quotes. For example:

```
Exec=sh /path/with/'Folder with spaces'/to/script.sh
```

(spaces in the path to your icon can/should be left as they are)

Comment: and don't forget to make executable your .desktop file  `chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/MYscript.desktop`:)

Comment: @KasiyA that is not necessary when you use it for Dash / Unity and store it in either ~/.local/share/applications` or `/usr/share/applications`. Most of the `.desktop` files are not in there.

Comment: But it's necessary for me cuz that's not appear in dash if it's not executable (MAY be my home folder is encrypted)

Comment: @KasiyA That is exceptional! Most applications install a .desktop file that is not executable. None of mine is in `/.local/share/applications` (and I have *a lot* there :) )