# How can I pass command line arguments to a script through Dash? (14.04)

Tags: scripts, unity-dash

I recently asked this question about adding a shell script to Dash:

[In 14.04 how do I run a bash script I wrote without opening a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540301/in-14-04-how-do-i-run-a-bash-script-i-wrote-without-opening-a-terminal)

It worked perfectly.

Follow-up question:  How can I pass command-line arguments through Dash?  Example:  In this case, my dash command is named "Panel".  The script panels my screen with 8 terminals.  Here's an example of the usage:

```
panel             # Tile the screen with 8 terminal windows.
panel --left      # Tile the left side with 4 terminals
panel --right     # Tile the right side with 4 terminals
```

And so on.  How can I pass arguments like `--left` or `--right` through Dash?  Ideally I'd like to have this workflow:

- Press the SUPER key
- Type `panel --left` (for example)
- Dash goes away and the left side is paneled.

Right now it runs the right script, but ignores `--left`.

Tips?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specify parameters for launcher program](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143422/specify-parameters-for-launcher-program)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu:  Thanks, but this is definitely not a duplicate of that.  That tells how to permanently affix options to a launcher program.  I want to be able to use different options whenever I want (without having multiple versions of the launcher).

Comment: Why not just use Alt+F2? That'd probably be easier.. Another option would be creating separate .desktop files..

Comment: ... or one .desktop file with a quicklist from the launcher.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot "run" a `.desktop` file from Dash with arguments, so the setup *exactly* like you have in mind is impossible I am afraid. However, assuming your script *does* take arguments, there are a few elegant alternative options, maybe even better:

---

1. Save your script in `~/bin`

   - remove the extension
   - make it executable
   - run it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, type the command

     ```
     <scriptname> <argument>
     ```

---

2. Create a quicklist in the Unity launcher:

   (assuming you saved the script in `~/bin`, made it executable and removed the extension as in 1.)

   [image]

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=name_of_your_script_like_you_see_it_in_Dash
   Exec=<scriptname> <default_argument>
   Icon=/path/to/some/icon
   Type=Application

   Actions=Panel;Panel -left;Panel -right;

   [Desktop Action Panel]
   Name=Panel
   Exec=<scriptname> <default_argument>
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;

   [Desktop Action Panel -left]
   Name=Panel -left
   Exec=<scriptname> <argument_1>
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;

   [Desktop Action Panel -left]
   Name=Panel -right
   Exec=<scriptname> <argument_2>
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;
   ```

   Save it as `panel.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications` and drag it on to the launcher.

---

3. Create three different keyboard shortcuts, for example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> to run your script+arguments:

   "System Settings" > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts"

   Click "+" to add your commands: `<scriptname> <argument>`

---

4. Not the most obvious one, but exploring the options, it should be mentioned: you can call a (zenity) option list from Dash:

   [image]

   Type the first character of your option, press return and your script will run with the chosen argument.

   [image]

   Again assuming that you saved the script in ~/bin, made it executable and removed the language extension as in 1.:

   - Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `panel_options.sh`, make it executable.

     ```
     #!/bin/bash

     test=$(zenity --list "1. Panel" "2. Panel -left" "3. Panel -right" --column="Panel options" --title="Panel")

     if [[ "$test" = "1. Panel"* ]]; then
         <scriptname> <default_argument>
     elif [[ "$test" = "2. Panel -left"* ]]; then
         <scriptname> <argument_1>
     elif [[ "$test" = "3. Panel -right"* ]]; then
         <scriptname> <argument_2>
     fi
     ```
   - Create the .desktop file from the code below. In the `Icon=` line, set the path to your icon, in the `Exec=` line the path to `pane_options.sh`, save it as `panel.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applicatios`

     ```
     [Desktop Entry]
     Name=Panel
     Exec=/path/to/panel_options.sh
     Icon=/path/to/some/icon
     Type=Application
     StartupWMClass=Zenity
     ```

Comment: Very thorough answer. +1

Comment: Very thorough; excellent answer.  Worth the bounty!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your original question, it looks like the right thing to do would be to move the script to `~/bin/`, which should be in your **`$PATH`** by default.
If you do this, you'll be able to run your script using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> again. You will also be able to pass arguments to it like you do in a shell.

You can also add any other folder where you keep your scripts to your **`$PATH`**. To do this, open `~/.profile` in the text editor of your choice:

```bash
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

At the end, add a line (replacing `<folder>` with your folder) and save the file:

```bash
PATH="<folder>:$PATH"
```

For example, I add `$HOME/.bin` to my **`$PATH`** so my binaries don't clutter my home folder, but you could add any directory to your path just be sure to not add anything dangerous (e.g. world-writeable).
The changes will take effect on the next login.