# .desktop file changing Exec depending on desktop environment

Tags: .desktop, xdg

I am trying to make a `.desktop` file on my desktop which opens a window of the file manager of the desktop env I'm currently in (Nautilus for Ubuntu, PCManFM for LXDE) but my file doesn't seem to work:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
X-Profiles=p0;p1;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false

[X-Action-Profile p0]
OnlyShowIn=LXDE;
Name=PCmanFM
Icon=pcmanfm
Exec=pcmanfm ~

[X-Action-Profile p1]
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
Name=Nautilus
Icon=nautilus
Exec=nautilus ~
```

Is the use of `X-Profile`key deprecated?
Do I need to supply a default `Exec` out of the profiles paragraphs?
I know from [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541122/how-can-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-script-through-dash-14-04) that I can make it a right-click quicklist, but I want it to only open a window of the current file-manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X-Action-Profile` is not part of the [Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html) but seems to be an extension by PCManFM. It doesn't work with most other programs.

Using

```
sh -c 'xdg-open "$HOME"'
```

as command for `Exec` should work.

For the icon the [Icon Naming Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html) defines `system-file-manager` as standard icon name so that should work with most icon themes

Comment: thanks! about the`Icon` field, is there some way to have the adequate icon in each DE?

Comment: The [Icon Naming Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html) defines `system-file-manager` as standard icon name so that should work with most icon themes.

Comment: Yeah, that worked great! Just add that to your answer and it will be complete. thanks!

Comment: @Moonstroke: Added.